# How to grew up a div to its container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know if we can set the height of a `div class="span6"` to its `row-fluid` container ?

Here is an example, i have a form on the left and a button on the right, how can i make the button the same height as the form on the left ?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Legend</legend>
          <label>Label name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
          <span class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</span>
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
          </label>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="span6"><button>Big Button</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any CSS you've already written for those elements?

Comment: No i only use bootstrap on this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the height of the left-hand `.span6` in javascript (jQuery). You could then apply that height to the css of the right-hand `.span6`. This would need `:next` or some form of traversing the DOM, or you could just rename the class of the right-hand button span that you want to be the same height.

```
left_h = $('.span6').height();
$('.span6 button').css('height',left_h);
```

You might have to tweak that a bit.